# sendKeys method throwing an error in selenium like"The method sendKeys(char sequence[] )in the type webelement is not applicable for the string"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

> this is my class*****

````
```
package automation;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/UMASHANKAR/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("https://sdzclient-kpiregister.azurewebsites.net/");
 driver.findElement(By.id("passwords")).sendKeys("Gravity@123");
     driver.findElement(By.id("btn-sdz-login")).click();
}
}
```
````

> on Hover the SendKeys method will get an error like"The method sendKeys(char sequence[] )in the type webelement is not applicable for the string".***

Comment: i have tried to change compiler version ..project>right click>build path>configure build path >java compiler> couldn't change compiler version.

Comment: anybody help me.

Comment: Which line you are getting issue  ? Also a one  more issue will there . Where you are launching your url. Although this would not result in compilation issue rather it will throw a run time ElementNotFound Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with Selenium you need to follow a few steps

```
//first you add your chrome driver path    
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/UMASHANKAR/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

// second you need to initialize the WebDriver object - and you did it
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

// third you need to tell to the WebDriver object where to go, what page to load 
driver.get("https://sdzclient-kpiregister.azurewebsites.net/"); 

//below is the login part
driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("SET_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE");
driver.findElement(By.id("passwords")).sendKeys("Gravity@123");
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-sdz-login")).click();
```

your error was throw because the driver didn't know where to go but you tried to send some keys instead of a driving page path

Comment: @Allan although you are right , in saying the steps we need to follow. But Divya  was facing compilation issue and not launching page can not be reason for compilation issue. As I mentioned in above comments, he would get run time error but above will not resolve the origionak issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, when you said you are not able to change compilation version. You can change as per below screen grab.

> ..project>right click>build path>configure build path >java compiler>

[image: Change Java Compiler version]

Do not forget to click on **Apply** after changing compilation version.

Comment: i have corrected the code as you said,but getting another error.                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "driver", = expected after this token
 The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) ChromeDriver

 at automation.Test1.main(Test1.java:13)

Comment: can you please help me to resolve this problem,i have added screenshot of the code in epic plz check.

Comment: can anybody help

Comment: You should always accept / upvote if your original issue is resolved as per any answer. Although I will look into another issue you are facing but in future you should start a fresh thread for new issue. Cheers :)

Comment: At what line you have got this error( as I can not Guess which is line 13) ? Also modify your question with current code you are trying to run ?

Comment: WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();     here i m getting error.